# My "Community Partners" are not appearing as they should

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here are my instructions:

> In this task, you will update the AboutScreen component to show the
> Mission and Community Partners of the company. You will only need to
> update the AboutScreen.js file.
>
> 1. You will use the Card layout similar to the ContactScreen to display the company mission statement. This should be implemented in a
>    separate functional component named Mission.
> 2. Use the Card, Card.Title, Card.Divider, and Text components in the Mission component.
> 3. On the Card component do not apply a wrapperStyle prop and on the Text component give it a style prop with margin: 10.
> 4. The mission statement should be preceded by a title of "Our Mission". You can use the Card.Title component for this, with a
>    Card.Divider after the title.
> 5. Text for the mission statement: a.  We present a curated database of the best campsites in the vast woods and backcountry of the World Wide
>    Web Wilderness. We increase access to adventure for the public while
>    promoting safe and respectful use of resources. The expert wilderness
>    trekkers on our staff personally verify each campsite to make sure
>    that they are up to our standards. We also present a platform for
>    campers to share reviews on campsites they have visited with each
>    other.
> 6. The community partnership information is obtained from the partners.js file in the shared folder by the AboutScreen component, so
>    you will need to import it. Set up a state variable inside the
>    function body of AboutScreen and initialize
> 7. Go to the empty ScrollView component that you set up in Task 1 in the AboutScreen function's return statement. Inside the ScrollView,
>    render the Mission component you set up earlier.
> 8. After the rendering of the Mission component, render a Card component with the title "Community Partners". Again, you can use a
>    Card.Title component for this with a Card.Divider after the title).
> 9. Then, inside the Card use the map method on the partners data passing partner as a parameter to the map method's function. (Remember
>    when using map in JSX you must put everything inside curly brackets)
> 10. Then the map's function should return a ListItem component. Make sure to set a key prop on the ListItem using the partner.id value.
>     (Unlike the Directory component, this ListItem will not need a onPress
>     prop nor the navigate function as, unlike the items in the Directory
>     screen, the items in this list will not be links.)
> 11. Use an Avatar component in the ListItem with the prop rounded and source setting the source prop to partner.image.
> 12. Use a ListItem.Content component below the Avatar tag nesting a ListItem.Title and ListItem.Subtitle between the opening and closing
>     tags and using the partner.name for the ListItem.Title and the
>     partner.description for the ListItem.Subtitle.

Here is the expected result:

[image]

vs what I'm getting:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Card, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { PARTNERS } from '../shared/partners';

const Mission = () => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Title>Our Mission</Card.Title>
      <Card.Divider />
      <Text>
        We present a curated database of the best campsites in the vast woods and backcountry of the World Wide Web Wilderness.
        We increase access to adventure for the public while promoting safe and respectful use of resources.
        The expert wilderness trekkers on our staff personally verify each campsite to make sure that they are up to our standards.
        We also present a platform for campers to share reviews on campsites they have visited with each other.
      </Text>
    </Card>
  );
};

const AboutScreen = () => {
  const renderPartner = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <ListItem
        title={item.name}
        subtitle={item.description}
        leftAvatar={{ source: item.image }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Mission />
      <Card>
        <Card.Title>Community Partners</Card.Title>
        <Card.Divider />
        <FlatList
          data={PARTNERS}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
        />
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AboutScreen;
```

Comment: Currently your code renders each item in the `<FlatList>` as: `<Text>{item.name}</Text>`  Which matches the output you're seeing.  It looks like the *desired* output is more complex than *just* a `<Text>` element, showing more data from `item` then just the `name` property.  So I suspect your next step is to simply... continue building the markup for the `renderItem` callback.